# Reaching root of recursive relation

Tags: sql, db2

Let's assume I have table of people which represents employees and relations between them (boss, subordinate). But there's no single root element (there's more than 1 row which do not have key pointing on boss). Can I write sql statement which for particular person tells me who is his top level supervisor?

here is example table

```
id, boss_fk
1
2    1
3    
4    2
5    4
6    3
```

So for instance for employee id = 6 it should be 3, whereas id = 5 it should be 1 (because 5->4->2->1).

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: It looks as if (employee id=6) does have (root=3) because (id=3) has a null value for boss_fk. (Well, null or blank or whatever that value is.) That's how you know you reached your 'root'. That's the same way you know you've reached the 'root' for (id=1).

Comment: @user2338816 is correct - this is essentially identical to existing hierarchical queries, simply in reverse.  Note that the db itself has no concept of 'root' or 'leaf' nodes - that's a meta-level construct.

Answer (score 0):

Last DB2-IDUG webminar talks about recursive operations in DB2: http://www.idug-db2.com?commid=105565

Or, if you prefer, you can create a recursive stored procedure: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/recursive_sql_pl?lang=en_us